# Show that $[(W\cup X)\cup(Y\cup Z)]-[(W\cup X)\cap(Y\cup Z)] \subset [(W\cup Y)-(W \cap Y)]\cup[(X\cup Z)-(X\cap Z)]$

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Walter Rudin, in his construction of the Lebesgue Measure in "Principles of Mathematical Analysis", defines the following function S

[image]

S is present in the following proposition

[image]

Define:

$A_1^c = W; \qquad A_2^c = X;\qquad  
B_1^c = Y; \qquad B_2^c = Z$

The midmost term of the proposition can be written as:

$[(W\cup X)\cup(Y\cup Z)]-[(W\cup X)\cap(Y\cup Z)] \subset [(W\cup Y)-(W \cap Y)]\cup[(X\cup Z)-(X\cap Z)]$

I would like to prove such proposition is true

Comment: Draw a Venn diagram, perhaps? It can be a bit tricky with four sets, but it is doable.

Comment: Good idea, but I want to see it proved in formal language.

Comment: http://imgur.com/wP8Zna8

Answer (score 1):

Outline: It suffices to show that
$$
(W\cup X)\cup(Y\cup Z) \subset [(W\cup Y)-(W \cap Y)]\cup[(X\cup Z)-(X\cap Z)] \cup [(W\cup X)\cap(Y\cup Z)].
$$
Split into three cases:

- $x$ in both $W\cup X$ and $Y\cup Z$;
- $x$ in $W\cup X$ but not $Y\cup Z$;
- $x$ in $Y\cup Z$ but not $W\cup X$.

Comment: After the split, what should I do?

Comment: In my opinion, it doesn't help you learn for me to write an entire proof. Like in any other problem, try thinking about one piece at a time. Is there any of the three cases where you can understand why such an element must be in the right-hand side?

Comment: Actually, I didn't quite understand what you meant by "split in three cases"

Comment: In general, to prove that $S\subset T$, you start by taking $x\in S$ and try to show that $s\in T$. So in this case, you start by taking $x\in (W\cup X)\cup(Y\cup Z)$.
— You might want to review fundamental logic steps and how to set up proofs. For example, you could go through Tim Gowers's posts: https://gowers.wordpress.com/category/cambridge-teaching/basic-logic/

Comment: OK. Let $w = a \in W; x = a \in X$ and so on. We have:

$(w \vee x) \rightarrow [(w \vee y) \wedge \neg (w \wedge y)] \vee [(x \vee z)\wedge \neg (x\wedge z)] \vee [(w \vee x)\wedge(y\wedge z)]$.

In my novice understanding of mathematics, I believe that what I seek is to prove such formula is a tautology by axioms and rules of inference. Notwithstanding, you seem to be able to do so by assigning truth values to complex formulas: the three cases you mentioned.
I would like to know how is this method of proof possible.

Comment: This isn't quite right. Logical operators (or, and, not, implies) should not be applied to elements of sets; they should be applied to sentences. For example, $t\in W\cup X$ is equivalent to $(t\in W)\lor(t\in X)$. It doesn't make any sense to choose $w\in W$ and $x\in X$ and write $w\lor x$.

Comment: w and x are not elements of sets, they are formulas. w stands for $ a \in W$ and x for $ a \in X $. In the language I'm using, only $a$ may denote an urelement.